# Check what GitHub pre-receive hooks do

Tags: github, hook, github-enterprise

Is there a way to inspect the script that gets executed for each **GitHub Enterprise pre-receive hook**?

All I'm seeing is a list of non clickable file (?) names:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> In the upper-right corner of any page, click

[image]

> In the left sidebar, click Admin center.

[image]

> In the left sidebar, click Webhooks.

[image]

> Next to the pre-receive hook that you want to edit, click

[image]

From the [GitHub Enterprise Server doc](https://help.github.com/en/enterprise/2.14/admin/developer-workflow/managing-pre-receive-hooks-on-the-github-enterprise-server-appliance#editing-pre-receive-hooks)

Comment: Thanks @AEIMehdi - Unfortunately I do not have admin access.